# Using 2 beans of the same type: javax.sql.DataSource in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a Spring Boot based application in which I would like to create 2 beans:  One will point to 'Oracle' database; the other will point to Hive.   I've declared them as follows:

```
public @Bean
BoneCPDataSource metadataDataSource() {
    BoneCPDataSource boneCPDataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
    boneCPDataSource.setDriverClass(getDriver());
    boneCPDataSource.setJdbcUrl(getJdbcUrl());
    boneCPDataSource.setUser(getUser());
    boneCPDataSource.setPassword(getPassword());
    boneCPDataSource.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(5);
    boneCPDataSource.setPartitionCount(5);
    return boneCPDataSource;
}

public @Bean
BasicDataSource hiveDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    // Note: In a separate command window, use port forwarding like this:
    //
    // ssh -L 127.0.0.1:9996:<server>:<port> -l <userid> <server>
    //
    // and then login as the generic user.

    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hive://127.0.0.1:9996:10000/mytable");
    return basicDataSource;
}
```

Problem is at the startup I am getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.dataSource;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected
single matching bean but found 2: metadataDataSource,hiveDataSource
```

Mainly because both of them inherit from javax.sql.DataSource. What's the best way to fix this?

---

EDIT:

Now I've declared them as follows:

```
public @Bean (name="metadataDataSource")
BoneCPDataSource metadataDataSource() {
    BoneCPDataSource boneCPDataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
    boneCPDataSource.setDriverClass(getDriver());
    boneCPDataSource.setJdbcUrl(getJdbcUrl());
    boneCPDataSource.setUser(getUser());
    boneCPDataSource.setPassword(getPassword());
    boneCPDataSource.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(5);
    boneCPDataSource.setPartitionCount(5);
    return boneCPDataSource;
}

public @Bean (name="hiveDataSource")
BasicDataSource hiveDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    // Note: In a separate command window, use port forwarding like this:
    //
    // ssh -L 127.0.0.1:9996:<server>:<port> -l <userid> <server>
    //
    // and then login as the generic user.

    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hive://127.0.0.1:9996:10000/mytable");
    return basicDataSource;
}
```

And got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.dataSource;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected
single matching bean but found 2: metadataDataSource,hiveDataSource
```

The other classes are referring to these beans as follows:

public class MetadataProcessorImpl implements MetadataProcessor {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("metadataDataSource")
BoneCPDataSource metadataDataSource;
```

@Controller
public class HiveController {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hiveDataSource")
BasicDataSource hiveDataSource;
```

Comment: Luiggi - I am not sure what you're suggesting.  Was my question not appropriate?  I googled for answers before asking this, but the results I got didn't really help.  But I must confess I didn't spend a lot of time going thru all of them.  Is that what I am expected to do?

Comment: I mean that you should accept the most useful post in your question as the answer. Sorry if my words didn't express that.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment: You should [accept the post that helped you most as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862) in your questions. After reviewing your profile, you have accepted none, so I recommend you to take some time to accept the bests answers (if any). There's a link in the comment that explains how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I didn't know about the 'accept' feature.  Will definitely use it going forward.

Comment: The problem is in this class: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration`. Can you see if you define this class or a subclass in XML or in another class within your project?

Comment: EndpointAutoConfigurtion is part of 'Spring Boot'.  It has the following:

 @Autowired(required = false)
 private DataSource dataSource;

This is the one that's causing the issue.  This works until I add the 2nd datasource ('hiveDataSource').

Comment: Then you have few options. Or you change the version of spring boot where this class doesn't contain that field or remove spring boot at all, another option may be removing one of your data sources but I don't think you want that.

Comment: Not using Spring Boot is not an option.  We're fairly committed to it.  Seems like it doesn't allow us to use more than one 'Data Source'.  That's sad :(  To get around it, I guess I can create a Singleton HiveDataSource for now.

Comment: You know, I read the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.java) of `EndpointAutoConfiguration` and there's no such class. Are you sure you're using the right version of spring boot?

Comment: There's no such class?  I debugged thru it.  It's located here:

\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!\org\springframework\boot\actuate\autoconfigure\EndpointAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it fast. It was field, not class.

Comment: After upgrading spring boot to 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version, started getting same error from:  DataSourceAutoConfiguration.  Seems like the code got moved around, but essentially we still can't use more than one 'Datasources' in Spring Boot - it appears!

Error creating bean with name.... org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: metadataDataSource,hiveDataSource

Comment: Well, looks like you have to talk to the software architecture team or the technical leader or the person that takes the technical decisions and explain this problem in detail to take the final decision on this after analyzing the impacts of the changes on the application design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give different names to your beans when using [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

```
@Bean(name="bonecpDS")
public BoneCPDataSource metadataDataSource() {
    //...
}

@Bean(name="hiveDS")
public BasicDataSource hiveDataSource() {
    //...
}
```

Then, when injecting the bean, use [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) and specify the name of the bean:

```
@Component
public class FooComponent {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bonecpDS")
    DataSource boneCPDataSource;
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me.  Added this:

    public @Bean (name="metadataDataSource")
    BoneCPDataSource metadataDataSource() {

Comment: @androidfan please do not post code in comments. Instead, edit your question and add the changes you've done at the bottom, also please don't remove the current content of the question.

Comment: @androidfan please post the code where you're attempting to inject the bean, looks like you haven't used the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: Let's just say for now that I am not using them.  Shouldn't the application start without any errors?

Comment: @androidfan this class: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration` is using it. Haven't you declare this class or a subclass somewhere else in your code or in XML configuration?

Comment: Sometimes you may need to assign datasource, transactionManager, and SqlSessionFactory as primary all.

Comment: One of the Datasource should be given as @Primary

Answer (score 20):

Set one of the beam as @Primary
as described in the section **67.2 Configure Two DataSources**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: the Primary was exactly my problem because of the : "default auto-configuration for JDBC or JPA " , thanks ! .

Comment: xml equivalent for @Primary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548471/spring-xml-equivalent-of-primary/45548585#45548585

Comment: This is the right answer, but I still don't understand when will this "@Primary" be used. Let's say you use only the non primary datasource calling it with a @Qualifier, why would u need the other one to be annotated "@Primary" ? Or is it just a buggy autoconf code whci checks how many objects of Datasource type are present without checking the bean names ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use two data sources at the same time and they are not primary and secondary, you should disable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` on your application annotated by `@SpringBootApplication(excludes = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`.

Since the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` will init the `DataSourceInitializer` class. The init method in `DataSourceInitializer` class needs to get `DataSource`. When there is more than one `DataSource`, the system gets confused by getting which `DataSource`.

`@SpringBootApplication(excludes = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` means that system won't load the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` when run the application.

Comment: Works like a charm!! I was looking for a solution for the problem for 2 days! I only have something to comment, it is misspelled "excludes", this should be: "exclude". Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Added @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})

and added manual configuration. It worked!