# Resource Annotation: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: exception, dependency-injection, spring-data

I am using Spring Java Based configuration for configure multiple database with Spring Data.
In the configuration file, i am creating two `data source` for `MySQL` and `MSSQL-Server`. When trying to inject dependency to the entity manager using `@Resource` annotation i am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mysql_datasource,secure_datasource
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1016)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
```

Following is my Code:

```
@Bean(name="secure_datasource")
public DataSource dataSource(){
    try{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("sc.db.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty("sc.db.driver.class"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("sc.db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("sc.db.password"));
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(7);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
        return dataSource; 
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

.................

@Bean(name="mysql_datasource")
public DataSource dataSource(){
    try{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty("db.driver.class"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(50);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(10);
        return dataSource; 
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

.......

@Resource(value="mysql_datasource")
@Bean(name="entity_manager_factory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("package.scan"));
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

I am also trying to use `@Qualifier` annotation as suggest i this link, but still getting error. [Using 2 beans of the same type: javax.sql.DataSource in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687369/using-2-beans-of-the-same-type-javax-sql-datasource-in-spring)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and after a lot of headache I stumbled upon this [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) that made me feel really dumb :(

All you need is @Primary on one of your DataSources and Spring-Boot won't get confused anymore... Here is one of my configurations... The rest are pretty much identical, pointing to other DBs and with no @Primary on them...

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"somepackage.entities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emfDB1", transactionManagerRef = "tmDB1", basePackages = {"somepackage.repositories"})
class PersistenceDB1 {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    DataSource dsDB1() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://someserver:3306/proativo");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfDB1() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dsDB1());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/DB1-persistence.xml");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "SEVERE"); // SEVERE / FINEST

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    JpaTransactionManager tmDB1() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emfDB1().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention: Probably due to the way my configuration classes are done, the method of excluding some classes on @EnableAutoConfiguration didn't work for me...

Comment: I added the @Primary directive but when I make the transaction manager, both of their session factories use the primary datasource. Is there a way to specifically tell the sessionfactory to use which datasource?

Comment: We probably need a bit of your code to figure out since, as you can see in the above code, the session manager is specified on the transaction manager creation.

Answer (score 7):

I my case, the configuration was on a xml file, so I only have to add the primary="true" to the bean tag of one of the defined datasources.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found this old post that explained it:

http://xantorohara.blogspot.ch/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

It looks like if you need multiple data sources, the Spring Boot magic runs out, and you have to take over the configuration manually.

In my case, I had to modify the EnableAutoConfiguration to take over the data source and transaction manager configuration myself:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

It looks like the Spring Boot magic ran out at the point I had to use multiple data sources...