# dataSource not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following code. When I try to execute it I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'x': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through field 'dataSource': No qualifying bean of type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency
>   [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

I tried adding in `resources` folder those lines in `application.properties`

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/y
jdbc.username=a
jdbc.password=b

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/y    spring.datasource.username=a
spring.datasource.password=b
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

or I tried adding this context config:

```
<!-- Initialization for data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cfa"/>
    <property name="username" value="cfa_user"/>
    <property name="password" value="cfa_pw"/>
</bean>
```

None of those worked. Any other ideas? Thanks!

I have to mention that my DAOs are extending

```
public abstract class BaseDAO extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {
    private @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initDataSource(){
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct starter modules in your dependencies?

Comment: I use maven. What should I have?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843788/resource-annotation-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource-is-define

Comment: If you use Maven, you should have Connector/J as a dependency: 

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I already had it included. I will update my post.

Comment: Try adding spring-boot-starter-jdbc instead of spring-jdbc, that should allow you to configure the datasource via the application.properties.

Comment: After adding spring-boot-starter-jdbc, I keep getting `Unable to proxy method [public final javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getDataSource()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.`

Comment: What do you need the NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport for anyway? Why not use a JDBCTemplate instead?

Comment: In documentation they recommend using `JdbcDaoSupport` or `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport`.

Comment: Feel free, I never used it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519940/what-is-jdbcdaosupport-used-for . Anyway, that message isn't an exception, so it will probably work anyway...