# Spring XML equivalent of @Primary

Tags: java, xml, spring

Is there an XML equivalent of **[@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)** that can promote one of the multiple qualifying beans

**Example Scenario:**

I've a spring-boot application with auto-configuration turned on. I've defined multiple datasources, however spring is unable to pick one of the datasources as its default.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mysqlDataSource,oracleDataSource
```

**datasources.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mcs" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test" />
        <property name="username" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Comment: <bean primary="true"/>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`<bean>` property has `primary` attribute:

```
<bean primary="true|false"/>
```

And remember:

> If a `@Primary`-annotated class is declared via XML, `@Primary` annotation
>   metadata is ignored, and `<bean primary="true|false"/>` is respected
>   instead.