# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat - No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi, embedded-tomcat-8

I am working on my spring boot application and running with embedded tomcat 8.x. I am trying to configure three different oracle data sources using JNDI and followed this [link](https://rdtschools.com/spring-boot-jndi-configurations-external-tomcat-multiple-datasources/). Below are my different files:

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS1.jndi-name=jdbc/oracleDS1
spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS2.jndi-name=jdbc/oracleDS2
spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS3.jndi-name=jdbc/oracleDS3
```

**OracleDataSourceConfiguration**

```
package com.adp.orbis.requesttracker.orbisrequesttracker;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;

    @Configuration
    public class OracleDataSourceConfiguration {

        @Value("${spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS1.jndi-name}")
        private String oracleDS1;

        @Value("${spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS2.jndi-name}")
        private String oracleDS2;

        @Value("${spring.oracle.datasource.oracleDS3.jndi-name}")
        private String oracleDS3;

        @Bean(name="dataSource1", destroyMethod = "")
        @Profile("dev")
        @Primary
        public DataSource evolutionDataSource() {
            JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(oracleDS1);
        }

        @Bean(name="dataSource2", destroyMethod = "")
        @Profile("dev")
        @Primary
        public DataSource orbisQueryOnlyDataSource() {
            JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(oracleDS2);
        }

        @Bean(name="dataSource3", destroyMethod = "")
        @Profile("dev")

        public DataSource orbisExportDataSource() {
            JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(oracleDS3);
        }
    }
```

**TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory**

```
@Bean
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ContextResource oracleDS1JNDIResource = new ContextResource();
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setName("jdbc/oracleDS1");
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydbservice1");
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setProperty("username", "db-user-name");
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setProperty("password", "db-user-pass");
                oracleDS1JNDIResource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(oracleDS1JNDIResource);

                ContextResource oracleDS2JNDIResource = new ContextResource();
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setName("jdbc/oracleDS2");
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydbservice2");
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setProperty("username", "db-user-name");
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setProperty("password", "db-user-pass");
                oracleDS2JNDIResource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(oracleDS2JNDIResource);

                ContextResource oracleDS3JNDIResource = new ContextResource();
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setName("jdbc/oracleDS3");
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydbservice3");
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setProperty("username", "db-user-name");
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setProperty("password", "db-user-pass");
                oracleDS3JNDIResource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(oracleDS3JNDIResource);                

            }
        };
    }
```

But when I run this spring boot application, it throws below exception. Could you please help me what I am missing here? I tried adding **@Primary** with all DataSource bean. But no luck.

**org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: dataSource1,dataSource2,dataSource3**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: dataSource1,dataSource2,dataSource3
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 2 beans of the same type: javax.sql.DataSource in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687369/using-2-beans-of-the-same-type-javax-sql-datasource-in-spring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue. The problem was, I had defined all data sources in my spring boot application and it was also importing dependent spring context file. That means, I had same data sources configured into my imported spring context file too. I removed all data source beans from OracleDataSourceConfiguration(as mentioned in my question on top) and used TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory to initialize JNDI data sources (referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container)) with the same name which are mentioned in my imported spring context file. It worked for me.

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be atleast 1 bean with name `dataSource`. So either replace any one of the existing bean with name for exp `dataSource1` to `dataSource`, or create a new one.

Trying to say, change

```
@Bean(name="dataSource1", destroyMethod = "")
@Profile("dev")
@Primary
public DataSource evolutionDataSource() {
     JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(oracleDS1);
}
```

To

```
@Bean(name="dataSource", destroyMethod = "")
@Profile("dev")
@Primary
public DataSource evolutionDataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(oracleDS1);
}
```

**OR** 
Simply remove `@Primary` from any of the existing `dataSource*` beans. At most 1 bean can have `@Primary` under same `@Profile`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried your both options. But no luck. I already have at least one bean name as dataSource.